# How to choose a left-add$(X)$-approximation with a certain property

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, approximation, exact-sequence

Let $A$ be an artin algebra and $X,Y$ in mod-$A$. Suppose $0\rightarrow Y \stackrel{\alpha}{\rightarrow} X^n\stackrel{\beta}{\rightarrow} X^m$ is exact.

Set $C:=Coker(\alpha)$ (as module) and $c:=coker(\alpha)$ (as a map).

> Why is it then possible to choose a left-$add(X)$-approximation $\varphi:C\rightarrow X^{\widehat{m}}$ (this means that the induced map Hom$_A(X^{\widehat{m}},Z)\rightarrow$Hom$_A(C,Z)$ is surjective for all $Z\in add(X)$) with the property that the sequence $0\rightarrow Y \stackrel{\alpha}{\rightarrow} X^n\stackrel{\gamma}{\rightarrow} X^{\widehat{m}}$, with $\gamma:=\varphi\circ c$, is still exact?

Thank you for your effort.

Comment: It is defined in the parentheses...that means that the induced map Hom$_A(X^m,Z)\rightarrow$Hom$_A(C,Z)$ is surjectve for all $Z\in add(X)$

Comment: Still unclear what's $add(X)$.

Comment: Oh ok...sorry...$add(X)$ denotes the full subcategory of mod-$A$ whose objects are direct summands of finite direct sums of copies of $X$.

Comment: Are you sure you want the same $m$ in the approximation $\varphi:C\to X^m$ as in the original map $\beta: X^n\to X^m$? If so, then I don't think you can choose such an approximation in general.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It is indeed not necessary that the two $m$'s coincide...I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sequence being exact at $X^n$ is equivalent to the map $\theta:C\to X^m$ induced by $\beta$ being injective.

If $\varphi:C\to X'$ is any left $\text{add}(X)$-approximation, then $\theta$ factors through $\varphi$, and so $\varphi$ must also be injective, and the resulting sequence $0\to Y\to X^n\to X'$ is exact.

Comment: Oh. It seems I was two minutes too late :-)

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon Or I was two minutes too early.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that there always exists a left-$add(X)$-approximation $\varphi:C\to X^{\widehat{m}}$ for any module $C$ in mod-$A$.  This comes from the fact that $Hom_A(C,X)$ is a finitely generated module over the (implicit) base ring $k$; if $f_1, \ldots, f_r$ are generators, then the map given in matrix form by $(f_1, \ldots, f_r)^t$ from $C$ to $X^r$ is an approximation.

Next, under the assumption of the question, we can prove that this $\varphi$ is injective.  Indeed, since the sequence $0\to Y\stackrel{\alpha}{\to} X^n \stackrel{\beta}{\to} X^m$ is exact, we have that $C$ is isomorphic to the image of $\beta$.  As a consequence, there is an injection $j:C\to X^m$.  Since $\varphi$ is a left-$add(X)$-approximation, $j$ factors through $\varphi$ (meaning that there is a $g:X^{\widehat{m}}\to X^m$ such that $g\varphi=j$).  Since $j$ is injective, $\varphi$ has to be as well.

Finally, we only have to concatenate the exact sequences $0\to Y \stackrel{\alpha}{\to} X^n \to C \to 0$ and $0\to C \stackrel{\varphi}{\to} X^{\widehat{m}}$ to obtain the exact sequence $0\to Y \stackrel{\alpha}{\to} X^n \to X^{\widehat{m}}$.